# Matrice conversion to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i have some issue when i want to convert this kind of input in pd.dataframe. This array is the resultat of a previous data collection of a raw html content with Beautifulsoup. When i tried to convert this double array with pandas.DataFrame function, i have an empty and curious result.

```
data=[['h1', '\n        An Example of Structure\n        '],
['p', "\n        Here's a typical paragraph.\n      "],
['ul', '\n'],
['li', '\n          Item one has an\n          '],
['a', '\n            anchor\n          '],
['h1', '\n        An Example of Structure\n        '],
['p', "\n        Here's a typical paragraph.\n      "],
['ul', '\n'],
['li', '\n          Item one has an\n          '],
['h1', '\n        An Example of Structure\n        '],
['p', "\n        Here's a typical paragraph.\n      "],
['ul', '\n'],
['li', '\n          Item one has an\n          '],
['a', '\n            anchor\n          ']]
```

Please, see mine hereunder output :

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[173]: 
       ...
    0  ...
    1  ...
    2  ...
    3  ...
    4  ...
    5  ...
    6  ...
    7  ...
    8  ...
    9  ...
    10 ...
    11 ...
    12 ...
   13 ...

    [14 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: It's working for me, I obtain tags in the first column and text in the second. That is what you expected?

Comment: It works too. It was in fact a display issue due to "/n" and space characters.

Comment: thank's for your help